# Each rank repeats itself over and over again

Tags: python, while-loop, iteration

I want totalxp to be carried on and added together each time the loop is ran, however i want the rank 1 to stop printing everytime i reach a higher rank.

```
import math
totalxp = 0
rank = 1
while totalxp < 2000:
  xpearned = int(input('Enter xp earned last game'))
  totalxp = xpearned + totalxp
  if totalxp >= 100:
    rank = 1
    print('You have been promoted to Corporal', rank)
    totalxp = totalxp - 100
    print(totalxp)
  if totalxp >= 300:
    rank = rank + 1
    print('You have been promoted to Sergeant', rank)
    totalxp = totalxp - 300
  if totalxp >= 700:
    rank = rank + 2
    print('You have been promoted to Staff Sergeant', rank)
    totalxp = totalxp - 700
  if totalxp >= 1500:
    print('You have been promoted to Warrant Officer', rank)
  print(totalxp)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason this is happening is because if a value is greater than 300, it must be greater than 100 and the first if statement will be executed. To avoid this, Just place the if statements which check for higher values above in your code and the if statements which check smaller values below. Also, use elif for the other if blocks.

```
import math
totalxp = 0
rank = 1
while totalxp < 2000:
  xpearned = int(input('Enter xp earned last game'))
  totalxp = xpearned + totalxp
  if totalxp >= 1500:
    print('You have been promoted to Warrant Officer', rank)
  elif totalxp >= 700:
    rank = rank + 2
    print('You have been promoted to Staff Sergeant', rank)
    totalxp = totalxp - 700
  elif totalxp >= 300:
    rank = rank + 1
    print('You have been promoted to Sergeant', rank)
    totalxp = totalxp - 300
  elif totalxp >= 100:
    rank = 1
    print('You have been promoted to Corporal', rank)
    totalxp = totalxp - 100
  print(totalxp)
```

Comment: Thank you so much. My computer science teacher does not answer me properly and I seek help from the community!

Comment: Thanks, can you mark the answer as correct?